# QMap and QPair, C++, Qt

Tags: c++, qt, data-structures

I want to make a data structure for accessing strings by two ways:

1. Access by ID
2. Access by name

My first idea is using two maps for each method but it leads to duplication of data:

```
QMap<int, QString> accessById;
QMap<QString, QString> accessByName;
```

I'm searching for a better way, something like this:

```
QMap<QPair<int, QString>, QString> multiAccess;
```

but it can not help me (at least I don't know how to do it), because searching in a map needs to know ID and name together. How can I define a well structure of Qt classes to achive my goal?

*No external libraries, but Qt*

Comment: [Boost MultiIndex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) is exactly what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about:

```
QMap<QString, int> nameIdMap;
QMap<int, QString> accessById;
```

You access by id and create a map for names and ids. Then you can access by name with

```
QString data = accessById[nameIdMap[the_name]];
```

Comment: +1 for paring down the memory requirement a bit, but do note that `QString` is implicitly shared under the hood so the double-lookup vs. memory may not be as clear a win as it might be with other string implementations: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/implicit-sharing.html

Comment: @MasoudM. `QPair` is only a fit here if as a key you wished to have `(1, "Foo")`, `(2, "Foo")`, `(1, "Bar")` etc. map to different values.  If you're interested in languages that are based on efficient pattern matching for wildcard keys like `(1, *)` or `(*, "Foo")` they're out there...but `QPair` in a `QMap` in C++ doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 4):

Qt doesn't have as much worry about duplication of data as many other class libraries do, because of "implicit sharing":

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/implicit-sharing.html

The list of classes which have this property (which include `QString`) is covered in that link.  There are helpers to create your own classes which use a Copy-On-Write strategy as well:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qshareddatapointer.html#details

To summarize: if you have a 10,000-character QString and assign it to another QString variable, you will not pay for another 10,000 characters of storage (unless you modify the string data of one of the two instances).  Still, even a read-only QString handle is a bit bigger than an `int`.  It depends on your scenario whether that size difference is significant vs. the speed tradeoff of multiple lookups, as in the strategy offered by @Juho.

Comment: +1: Well points for me. Ok, How can i put QStrings to two maps which `implicit sharing` applies to them?

Comment: As indicated by the term "implicit", it just works without you having to do anything special.  Every time you do a QString assignment (including as a key or value in a map), the assignment won't make a copy of the underlying string data.  Each new value-copied QString will just be a pointer to shared data...up until someone, somewhere, writes to their instance.  At the time of writing, the data is duplicated.  All of this happens in a thread-safe manner behind-the-scenes.

Comment: So if i write `QString a="Hello";` and `QString b="Hello";` then `a` and `b` refers to a shared block of data?

Comment: Well it might...but if it did, that wouldn't have anything to do with Qt but rather a compiler feature known as "constant pooling" or "string interning" that you can investigate if you wish.  The case is more about `QString a="Hello";` and `QString b=a;`, which doesn't require runtime string compares to make decisions on memory management...

Comment: Note: Looking at the Qt sources, there is no checking to see if the passed in `char*` pointer is the same across multiple calls, so your version of the a/b example would definitely allocate separate data...even if the compiler pooled the constants and passed the same address in twice.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [Boost Bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/boost_bimap/one_minute_tutorial.html) which will create a bidirectional map between the id and Name.

```
boost::bimap<int, QString> idNameBimap;
```